# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b"stock_df

Tags: python

My code is:

```
 def save_sp500_tickers():
resp = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
tickers = []
for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
    ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text.replace('.', '-')
    ticker = ticker[:-1]
    tickers.append(ticker)
with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(tickers, f)
return tickers
def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):
if reload_sp500:
    tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
else:
    with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
        tickers = pickle.load(f)
if not os.path.exists('stock_df'):
    os.makedirs('stock_df')
start = dt.datetime(2019, 6, 8)
end = dt.datetime.now()
for ticker in tickers:
    print(ticker)
    if not os.path.exists('stock_df/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
        df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start, end)
        df.reset_index(inplace=True)
        df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
        df.to_csv('stock_df/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
    else:
        print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))
save_sp500_tickers()
get_data_from_yahoo()
def compile_data():
with open('sp500tickers.pickle','rb') as f:
    tickers = pickle.load(f)        
main_df = pd.DataFrame()    
for count,ticker in enumerate(tickers):
    df = pd.read_csv('stock_df/{}.csv'.format(tickers))
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True, drop=True)
    df.rename(columns={'Adj Close':ticker}, inplace=True)
    df.drop(['Open','High','Low','Close','Volume'],1, inplace=True)
    if main_df.empty:
        main_df = df
    else:
        main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')
    if count % 10 == 0:
        print(count)            
print(main_df.head())
main_df.to_csv('sp500_joined_closes.csv')    
compile_data()`
```

I get the error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b"stock_df/['MMM', 'ABT',... 'ZION', 'ZTS'].csv". I'm not really sure what do do since i have saved the file before i start compiling them. Is it how i saved the file?

Comment: Hello, you should cut out everything that isn't related to your error, and try to remove things from your example until only code related to your bug is left. This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I will make sure to use this format next time. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you possibly intending to pass ticker instead of tickers? Try this on that first line in the for loop instead:

`df = pd.read_csv('stock_df/{}.csv'.format(ticker))`

(for posterity — previously you passed `tickers` here instead)

I reckon you probably have a file for each ticker.